# Is it possible to listen the click of a bluetooth button?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I want to launch remotely a http request through my android App.

Is it possible to use for example this bluetooth selfie button
http://www.dx.com/fr/p/wireless-bluetooth-v3-0-selfie-camera-remote-controller-shutter-for-ios-android-devices-black-353773#.VIIaIzGG8kQ 
in order to execute a http request ?

So the question is : is it possible to listen the click of this bluetooth button ?
If so how to do it ?

This bluetooth button is aimed at taking pictures.
Or do you see another hardware to action remotely a http request ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually achieve this. I am not sure about that particular bluetooth button, but I have done it with others, so the principle should be the same.

These buttons usually are paired like bluetooth keyboards to the device. Once they are connected your activity gets signals that corresponds to a keyboard key clicks (usually the enter key, which triggers the shutter in the standard camera app). This means you can overwrite `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` and check if it was the keyCode your bluetooth button sends. If that is the case, just do your http request, or whatever else you like.

In order to connect to the button, you have to write your own broadcast receiver and listen to
the different actions.

Take a look at `ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED` and `ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST` for bonding to the bluetooth button and then at
`ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED`, `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED`, `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED`, `ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` for handling the different states.

Also take a look at the developer documentation for bluetooth devices here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: Hello, Can I ask you something , I have an Bluetooth device that is Smart Tracker and has only one button , is possible to listen in this event? And also how can I connect to this device ? Thanks in advance .